# How does one print a variable at the MongoDB command prompt?

Tags: mongodb

How does one print a variable at the MongoDB command prompt. Unbelievably, I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
> var i = 0;
> i
0
> print(i)
0
>
```

Use either as appropriate. Happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: I did: > thing = db.things.find() and then > thing, which didn't work. I think here thing is not a normally printable object (as I had first thought)?

Comment: find() returns a cursor, not the result document(s)

Answer (score 3):

You can execute Java Script in Mongo CLI or command prompt 
The print() method simply prints the data arguments that are passed into it. 
print("Hello From Mongo");

eg:

```
print(data, ...);
printjson(object);
print(JSON.stringify(object));
```

The printjson() method prints a pretty form of the JavaScript object. The print(JSON.stringify(object)) method also prints a tightly compact string form of a JavaScript object.